# Unable to synchronize with Ropsten testnet with Geth 1.9.25

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, synchronization, ropsten, testnets

For the past two days I've been trying to synchronize with Ropsten testnet using the following command in Geth 1.9.25:

```
./geth --ropsten --rpc --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" --rpcapi="eth, web3, personal" --syncmode=fast --cache=2048 --bootnodes "enode://6332792c4a00e3e4ee0926ed89e0d27ef985424d97b6a45bf0f23e51f0dcb5e66b875777506458aea7af6f9e4ffb69f43f3778ee73c81ed9d34c51c4b16b0b0f@52.232.243.152:30303,enode://94c15d1b9e2fe7ce56e458b9a3b672ef11894ddedd0c6f247e0f1d3487f52b66208fb4aeb8179fce6e3a749ea93ed147c37976d67af557508d199d9594c35f09@192.81.208.223:30303"
```

Unfortunately, the node is approzimately 3000 blocks ahead of Etherscan.
Local: 10032595, Etherscan ropsten: 10029763
When I run `eth.getBlockByNumber("10029763")`, block and miner hashes do not match with etherscan.

The bootnode config was taken from [official ropsten github](https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootnodes on the commandline are no longer needed. That repo was created when ropsten was attacked a few years ago. New client version should have the correct bootnodes.

Around 10 Mar 2021 Ropsten was forked to Berlink, see announcement on [Ethereum blog](https://blog.ethereum.org/2021/03/08/ethereum-berlin-upgrade-announcement/). In order to synchronize to the correct branch use geth v1.10.1 at least.